# Save OpenCV Viz3d window frame directly to cv::Mat?

Tags: opencv

There is a [saveScreenshot()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/viz/doc/viz3d.html#viz-viz3d-savescreenshot), but what about saving directly to a OpenCV Mat?

It's not too hard to save to a temp location and then immediately reload with imread, but that is ugly, as would be going deeper down into the OS window manager and grabbing the contents of a window from there.